# SQL GROUP BY with a custom order

Tags: mysql

I have a database table with answers for different questions. Now I need an evaluation for this table and I want to perform it in SQL.

The `answer` table with some data:

| id | item_id | user_id | percent | input_id | weekday | week | list_id | date | prio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21580 | 517 | 1 | 0 | 1058 | Mo | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-17 | 1 |
| 845 | 517 | 16 | 100 | 1057 | Mo | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-17 | 2 |
| 21641 | 517 | 1 | 100 | 1057 | Di | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-18 | 1 |
| 943 | 517 | 33 | 100 | 1057 | Di | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-18 | 3 |
| 21766 | 517 | 1 | 0 | 1058 | Mi | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-19 | 1 |
| 1005 | 517 | 33 | 100 | 1057 | Mi | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-19 | 3 |
| 21703 | 517 | 1 | 100 | 1057 | Do | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-20 | 1 |
| 1072 | 517 | 33 | 100 | 1057 | Do | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-20 | 3 |
| 21772 | 517 | 1 | 0 | 1058 | Fr | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-21 | 1 |
| 1107 | 517 | 33 | 100 | 1057 | Fr | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-21 | 3 |
| 1162 | 517 | 33 | 0 | 1058 | Sa | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-22 | 3 |
| 1223 | 517 | 1 | 100 | 1057 | So | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-23 | 8 |

I used the following query to get those results.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM answer 
  WHERE item_id = 517 
  AND week = '2022-03' 
  ORDER BY date asc, prio asc;
```

Now I need the weekdays only once in that order that is shown above. I tried to use `GROUP BY` but it did not work in that way I need it. So what I need is this:

| id | item_id | user_id | percent | input_id | weekday | week | list_id | date | prio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21580 | 517 | 1 | 0 | 1058 | Mo | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-17 | 1 |
| 21641 | 517 | 1 | 100 | 1057 | Di | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-18 | 1 |
| 21766 | 517 | 1 | 0 | 1058 | Mi | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-19 | 1 |
| 21703 | 517 | 1 | 100 | 1057 | Do | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-20 | 1 |
| 21772 | 517 | 1 | 0 | 1058 | Fr | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-21 | 1 |
| 1162 | 517 | 33 | 0 | 1058 | Sa | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-22 | 3 |
| 1223 | 517 | 1 | 100 | 1057 | So | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-23 | 8 |

What I get when I use `GROUP BY weekday` is this:

````
SELECT * 
  FROM answer 
  WHERE item_id = 517 AND week = '2022-03' 
  GROUP BY weekday 
  ORDER BY date asc, prio asc```
````

| id | item_id | user_id | percent | input_id | weekday | week | list_id | date | prio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 845 | 517 | 16 | 100 | 1057 | Mo | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-17 | 2 |
| 943 | 517 | 33 | 100 | 1057 | Di | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-18 | 3 |
| 1005 | 517 | 33 | 100 | 1057 | Mi | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-19 | 3 |
| 1072 | 517 | 33 | 100 | 1057 | Do | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-20 | 3 |
| 1107 | 517 | 33 | 100 | 1057 | Fr | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-21 | 3 |
| 1162 | 517 | 33 | 0 | 1058 | Sa | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-22 | 3 |
| 1223 | 517 | 1 | 100 | 1057 | So | 2022-03 | 23 | 2022-01-23 | 8 |

This is the ruleset for the evaluation:
I need the newest answer based on the priority of that answer.
Every user can have for every list a specific priority. `1` is the highest and `10` (default) the lowest.
So if `10` users answer the same question at the same day, I only need the newest answer with the lowest integer value form the `prio` column. That's why I `ORDERY BY prio ASC`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is the ruleset that tells us you want percent 100 as opposed to 0 for Monday 17th? Is it just based on the highest id value in the grouping?

Comment: No it's based on the prio column. Every user can have for every list a specific priority. 1 is the highest and 10 the lowest. So for the evaluation I only need the newest answer with the highest prio per day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this fit your needs? It works by getting min(prio) per group by item_id, date -

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM answer a
JOIN (
    SELECT item_id, date, MIN(prio) min_prio
    FROM answer
    WHERE item_id = 517
    AND week = '2022-03'
    GROUP BY item_id, date
) t ON a.item_id = t.item_id
    AND a.date = t.date
    AND a.prio = t.min_prio
```